# Show products from above 99$ price in Woocommerce using shortcode or php code

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, hook-woocommerce

I am searching for a conditional shortcode based on product price. I have 2k+ products on Woocommerce now and I want to show products above 99$ price from a specific category and from whole products.

How can I apply this conditions in the shortcode? Is there any way to do this?

Actually, I want to apply in a widget, so shortcode form will work.

Below is simple `shortcode` to show products but I want to apply this needed condition:

```
[products limit="10" columns="4" category="hoodies, tshirts"]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update on August 2018: (added 'type' => 'DECIMAL', to the meta_query array)

> For WooCommerce 3.3+ you can better use: 
> [Display on a page all products below a specific price in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715447/display-on-a-page-all-products-below-a-specific-price-in-woocommerce/51830954#51830954)

This is possible tweaking the shortcode with a **fake category** that contain the price like for your case: `price-above-99` where `'above'` will be the operator `'>'` and **`'99'`** the price amount. The operator can also be:

- `price-below-20` ( where `'below'`  the operator `'<'` and **`'20'`** the price amount ).
- `price-equal-25` ( where `'below'`  the operator `'='` and **`'25'`** the price amount ).

Now your shortcode *(with the fake category)* will be:

```
[products limit="10" columns="4" category="hoodies, tshirts, price-above-99"]
```

Here is the code of the function that will allow that:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'shortcode_products_price', 10, 3 );
function shortcode_products_price( $query_args, $atts, $loop_name ) {
    $has_price = false;
    $compare = $price = '';
    $categories = $atts['category'];
    $categories = str_replace(' ', '', $categories);
    $categories_array = explode(',', $categories);
    if( count($categories_array) > 0 )
        foreach( $categories_array as $category )
            if (strpos($category, 'price-') !== false) {
                $has_price = true;
                $values = explode('-', $category);
                if( 'above' == $values[1] ) $compare = '>';
                elseif( 'below' == $values[1] ) $compare = '<';
                else $compare = '=';
                $price = $values[2];
            }

    if( $has_price )
        $query_args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key'     => '_price',
            'value'   => $price,
            'type'    => 'DECIMAL', // <== Updated
            'compare' => $compare,
        );

    return $query_args;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).

> **It works quiet well on simple products**, but for **variable products**, as they have many prices, it will take the highest price (in your case)...

If you want to **exclude variable products** you will replace the **meta query** array **`$query_args['meta_query']`** by this:

```
if( $has_price )
    $query_args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => '_regular_price',
            'value'   => $price,
            'type'    => 'DECIMAL', // <== Updated
            'compare' => $compare,
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => '_sale_price',
            'value'   => $price,
            'type'    => 'DECIMAL', // <== Updated
            'compare' => $compare,
        )
    );
```

This will remove variable products …

Comment: thanks sir. shortcode is working. but i try to increase the no. of columns  from 4 to 6 its not working . can you help me about this ?  is this because of theme ?

Comment: @UsmanAli Yes may be, sorry I don't know… but 6 product by row is a lot. Look on the docs: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/ … I don't do any theming or styling personally.

Comment: this does not work in WooCommerce 4.x. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715447/display-on-a-page-all-products-below-a-specific-price-in-woocommerce/51830954#51830954) works fine on v4.

Comment: @Raptor Added that on this answer… So if [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715447/display-on-a-page-all-products-below-a-specific-price-in-woocommerce/51830954#51830954) works fine on v4 for you I suppose you upvoted it…