# Display on a page all products below a specific price in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, price

I have a Woocommerce store with more than 1000 products. I would like that all products which have a price below **999** should be shown on a separate page, so I can tag that Page in my menu.

Is it possible?

Comment: I have edited my question.
Kindly help if have a solution for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** *(added `'type' => 'DECIMAL',` to the `meta_query` array)*

This can be done using [Woocommerce shortcode](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-6) **`[products]`** to be used on a page, with the following additional code *(that will add the possibility to define a price to be compared through an existing argument)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'products_based_on_price', 10, 3 );
function products_based_on_price( $query_args, $atts, $loop_name ) {
    if( ! ( isset($atts['class']) && ! empty($atts['class']) ) )
        return $query_args;

    if (strpos($atts['class'], 'below-') !== false) {
        $compare   = '<';
        $slug    = 'below-';
    } elseif (strpos($atts['class'], 'above-') !== false) {
        $compare   = '>'; //changed from "<" to ">"
        $slug    = 'above-';
    }

    if( isset($compare) ) {
        $query_args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key'     => '_price',
            'value'   => (float) str_replace($slug, '', $atts['class']),
            'type'    => 'DECIMAL',
            'compare' => $compare,
        );
    }
    return $query_args;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

##USAGE:

> Here we use the unused **`class`** argument to pass the price and the comparison operator.

**1) DISPLAY PRODUCTS BELOW A SPECIFIC AMOUNT** *(YOUR CASE)*

You will paste the following shortcode example with as `class` argument value `below-999` *(for products that have a price below 999)*:

```
[products limit="16" paginate="true" columns="4" class="below-999"]
```

**The wordpress page text content editor:**

[image]

You will get:

[image]

**2) DISPLAY PRODUCTS ABOVE A SPECIFIC AMOUNT**

You will paste the following shortcode example with as `class` argument value `above-50` *(for products that have a price above ***`50`***)*:

```
[products limit="16" paginate="true" columns="4" class="above-50"]
```

---

Available shortcode arguments and settings: [**Woocommerce shortcodes documentation**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-6)

Comment: Ok thanks i will try it and give feedback here. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @AnindyaGoel This really works, and Woocommerce shortcodes have a lot of different available arguments to make it just as you want.

Comment: Hi
I tried the mentioned code but it is showing all the products in my store.

Comment: [Update]- I just found a mistake in function coding, operator was mistyped for Below Conditional statement.
It should be ">" in case of Below condition in the above mentioned coding. 
Well thanks again for help :)

Comment: Hi there is one more issue with that,
when i type class="below-999" it is not showing any product.
And when I just type "9" instead of "999" it shows products below 999.
Why is it happening and for your information my store currency is INR(₹).

Comment: its ok you can let me know anytime

Comment: @AnindyaGoel Ok found the problem and updated the code…

Answer (score 1):

- Create a new page template
- Create a new page, assign new page template
- On top of page template code (or using filters), use WP_query to query your products

See:

```
$query = new \WP_Query(
    [
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'post_type' => 'product',
      'meta_key' => '_price',
      'meta_value' => 999,
      'meta_compare' => '<',
      'meta_type' => 'NUMERIC'
    ]);
```

- You can then use a while loop, or foreach on `$query->posts` to display your post

Comment: I don't know how to post this Query,
Please explain.

Comment: You can foreach on the $query->posts and you'll have your posts to display