# Cannot declare class PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception, because the name is already in use

Tags: php, phpmailer

The error:
`Cannot declare class PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception, because the name is already in use.`

Below is the code being used

```
 require '/home3/afaflawm/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require '/home3/afaflawm/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require '/home3/afaflawm/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
// Load Composer's autoloader
 require 'vendor/autoload.php';
   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
 use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
 use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
   function SendSMTPemail(){
  try {
 $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
  $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;  
    $mail->Host='ssl';
       $mail->isSMTP();                                            
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   
     $mail->Username='xy@xy.com'; 
    $mail->Password='xxxxxxx'; 
       $mail->setFrom('xy@xy.com');
       $mail->AddAddress('yz@yz.com');                             // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port       = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to
    $mail->addReplyTo('ab@ab.com', 'Information');
        $mail->isHTML(true);  
   $mail->Subject = "Appointment Details";
    $mail->Body    = "Dear, <br> Please be informed that you have an appointment  tommorow   <br>      Regards <br> ";
    $mail->AltBody = '';
   if(!$mail->Send()) {
           echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
         echo "Message sent!";
    }
     //echo "success";
        // $globals['emailstatus'] =true;
        // header("Location: sendEmail.php");
   } catch (Exception $e) {
       //echo "fail";
           // $globals['emailstatus'] =false;
    echo "Message could not be sent.";
   }
     }
   SendSMTPemail();
```

If following lines of code are commented,

```
   require '/home3/afaflawm/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
   require '/home3/afaflawm/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
   require '/home3/afaflawm/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
```

Then it shows the following error:

```
   Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP' not found
```

If following lines of code are commented,

```
   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
```

Then it shows the following error:

```
     Cannot declare class PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception, because the name is already in use
```

Following is the directory and its placement:
[image]

I had once used PHPMailer previosuly using Gmail's SMTP which was working fine. Can someone help as to why this error is being displayed though the required files are in the right directory?

**Findings (Edits)**
I realized there is a PHPMailer folder residing in also wp_content folder as well as wp_includes. I had uploaded PHPMailer  folder to wp_content long time ago when I was working with PHPmailer for gmail. I have multiple copies of this folder in the files. One in the root directory in vendor folder which was created by composer and others in wp_content and wp_includes. wp_includes is strange as I dont know if the composer created or what.. What should I do. I would like to just use the one in wp_content as it was working fine when I had used it using gmail SMTP @Synchro

Comment: i think no need to use require, you can register the package in composer.json if you use composer, autoload.php will load automatically

Comment: It was already installed using composer. But when commenting the require statements, it shows a different error i.e. ```Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP' not found ```

Comment: Try with command `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: if you are using composer no need to require. composer will automatically load class after making object. you should just namespace at the top

Comment: Either use composer (recommended) or load classes manually; don’t mix them. Make sure you don’t have any other copies of PHPMailer lurking in other places that might match entries in your include paths.

Comment: remove all require statements except autoload.php line
also comment 'SMTP' include line and ALL code which use SMTP class 
you will not need SMTP class to send mail in your code you have use to just get a static variable declared in SMTP class 
than check

Comment: Based on my findings, there are many PHPMailer folders residing in the files. Please check the edited question as the comment doesnt allow detailed explanation @Synchro

Comment: @sta . I ran that command. it displayd the following message 'Generated autoload files containing 0 classes'

Comment: Current wordpress (5.5) includes a recent version of PHPMailer, so I would recommend using that directly rather than including your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I kept the first two lines commented while the third one for SMTP uncommented and it started working

```
  //require '/home3/afaflawm/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
  //require '/home3/afaflawm/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
  require '/home3/afaflawm/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
```

So the problem was caused by the first two require statements as they were already loaded by the composer on this line  `require 'vendor/autoload.php'` except the SMTP. Therefore the error was displaying in both cases when I tried commenting all three lines once and composer the other time separately

Answer (score 9):

Try something like

```
if (!class_exists('PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception'))
{
  require '/home3/afaflawm/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
  require '/home3/afaflawm/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
  require '/home3/afaflawm/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
}
```

Comment: Please don't edit any of my answers code without asking before… The edit you did [here was wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51830954/3730754)…

Answer (score 4):

Based on @Far findings, the answer is:

```
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp- 
includes/PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/PHPMailer/SMTP.php';
```

Comment: yep, `require_once` makes sure it won't be included second time. my error was caused because I've put require statements inside a function that sends email, so then function was called second time error was triggered