# Display on a page all products between £50 - £100 in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, price

I'm setting up a "shop by price" dropdown on my site, in it you'll see a couple pages showing all products of a specific price range.

Thanks to *[Display on a page all products below a specific price in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715447/display-on-a-page-all-products-below-a-specific-price-in-woocommerce/51830954#51830954)* answer code, I've got it working for "below £50" and "above £600".

But my issue is when I try to specify a price range £50 - £100 for example.

Any ideas on how I'd feed a min and max value to a similar function like the one below?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed, the answer submitted before you closed it has worked therefore "debugging info" wasnt needed and "desired behaviour" was communicated across. Please reopen to help others in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with wordpress, but you can edit the function in that way to have what you need.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'products_based_on_price', 10, 3 );
function products_based_on_price( $query_args, $atts, $loop_name ) {
    if( ! ( isset($atts['class']) && ! empty($atts['class']) ) )
        return $query_args;

    if (strpos($atts['class'], 'below-') !== false) {
        $compare   = '<';
        $slug    = 'below-';
    } elseif (strpos($atts['class'], 'above-') !== false) {
        $compare   = '<';
        $slug    = 'above-';
    } elseif (strpos($atts['class'], 'between-') !== false) {
        $compare   = '<>';
        $slug    = 'between-';
    }

    if( isset($compare) ) {
        if(strlen( $compare == 1))
        {
            $query_args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key'     => '_price',
                'value'   => (float) str_replace($slug, '', $atts['class']),
                'type'    => 'DECIMAL',
                'compare' => $compare,
            );
        }
        else
        {
            foreach( str_split($compare) as $key => $value )
            {
                $query_args['meta_query'][] = array(
                    'key'     => '_price',
                    'value'   => (float) explode('-', str_replace($slug, '', $atts['class']))[$key],
                    'type'    => 'DECIMAL',
                    'compare' => $value,
                );
            }
        }
    }
    return $query_args;
}
```

Use the class as `between-50-100`